# How to create parent-child object from array of sibling objects and filter elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to create this object:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "javascript": [
      {
        "product": "1234",
      },
      {
        "product": "4321",
      }
    ]
  },  
  {
    "python": [
      { 
        "product": "9876",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here on code snippet is the original object I'm trying to parse:

```js
const myData = [
  {
    "category": "javascript",
    "product": "1234"
  },
  {
    "category": "javascript",
    "product": "4321"
  },
  {
    "category": "python",
    "product": "9876"
  },
];


const mountCategories = (data) => {
  const categoriesObj = data.map(value => value.category).filter((value, index, a) => a.indexOf(value) === index)
  
  const categorizedData = categoriesObj.map((value) => {
    return {
      value: data.map(value => {
        return {
          product: value.product,
        }
      })
    }
  });
  
  return (
    categorizedData
  )

}
console.log(mountCategories(myData))
```

I'm not being able to get the category key string to work. Also I need to figure how to filter the elements properly.

Comment: Why did you pick that specific structure? Each of the objects in `data` only has a single key, and you have to guess its name basically, or use `Object.keys(..)[0]`. I'd use two keys, `language` and `products` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const myData = [
  {
    "category": "javascript",
    "product": "1234"
  },
  {
    "category": "javascript",
    "product": "4321"
  },
  {
    "category": "python",
    "product": "9876"
  },
];

let result = myData.reduce((acc,current) => {
   let prev = acc.find(doc => doc[current.category]);
   if(!prev){
      prev = { [current.category]: [] };
      acc.push(prev);
   }
   prev[current.category].push({product: current.product});
   
   return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm trying to add a key to categories, I'm trying to edit this line `prev = { [current.category]: [] };` to something like this `prev = { ["category": current.category]: [] };` and it's not working (what is the `:` for?`). Also I think in adding the key I'd need to set an `obj` not an `array` as `child` properties.

Comment: `{ ["category": current.category]: [] }` is syntactically invalid, maybe you need: `{ "category": { [ current.category]: [] } }` ?

Comment: I think I tried that, but since push method was warning `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined ` on below line, I thought the problem was the syntax

Comment: I think you need that plus `prev.category[current.category].push({product: current.product});`